# iOS: Realm subscription state never updated

Tags: ios, swift, realm, subscription

I'm having an issue with Realm subscriptions observers. The state is not updating after receiving data from the server. I'm using this code below:

```
        let realm = try! Realm(configuration: try configuration(url: realmURL))
        let results: Results<Object> = realm!.objects(Object.self)
        let subscription = results.subscribe(named: "objects")


        subscription.observe(\.state, options: .initial) { state in
        print("Sync State Objects: \(state)")}
```

The only state I get is ".creating" and after that nothing more is updated. I would like to get ".completed" to be able to track progress of the subscription getting data.
Important to mention that I already tried to remove the options but in this case even ".creating" is not triggered.

Thanks

Comment: There's really not enough code in the question to understand the issue and syncService and .subscribeObjects use is inclear. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Generally speaking though when you create a subscription it returns a notification token, which is stored as a class var. Perhaps the function is going out of scope?

Comment: Hi, basically when observe the state of a subscription I never get other states besides .initial. Never get .completed for example.

Comment: The code in your question is not Realm code. There is no syncService.subscribeObjects function so it's unclear what you're trying to do. Also, why is the question marked with the subscription tag as that has nothing to do with working with Realm.

Comment: Sorry @Jay, maybe the code was not clear enough, please take a look, it is about Realm. Object is just a sample class for the question.

Comment: It looks like you are missing quite a bit of code. You need to have a notification token that can react the the changes. See [Registering for notifications](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/syncing-data#registering-for-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer with some partial code as it will provide some directon to get this working. Assume we have a PersonClass, a tableView and a tableView dataSource called personResults. This was typed here so don't just copy paste as I am sure there are a couple of build errors.

In our viewController...

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
   let realm: Realm
   let personResults: Results<Person>
   var notificationToken: NotificationToken?
   var subscriptionToken: NotificationToken?
   var subscription: SyncSubscription<Project>!
```

then later when we want to start sync'ing our personResults

```
subscription = personResults.subscribe()
subscriptionToken = subscription.observe(\.state, options: .initial) { state in
    if state == .complete {
        print("Subscription Complete")
    } else {
        print("Subscription State: \(state)")
    }
}

notificationToken = personResults.observe { [weak self] (changes) in
    guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
    switch changes {
    case .initial:
        // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
        print("observe: initial load complete")
        tableView.reloadData()
    case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
        // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                             with: .automatic)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                             with: .automatic)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                             with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    case .error(let error):
        // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: so my problem is that the state for subscription never returns .complete, only .initial.

Comment: @ArildoJunior If that's the case then there's something else wrong and the code in the question is not complete enough to know what. The code in this answer was essentially taken directly from a working project so conceptually it's sound. Again though, as I mentioned in the comments to your question, you're missing quite a bit of code and probably missing a step as well. Can you update and clarify the question? We'll take a look and update the answer once we see that.